# Activity animation does not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Edited: When the activity opens next activity, In the  push_down_in.xml and push_down_out.xml, only the last translate animation is being animated. the first translate tag is not being animated. I want to make the animation like two different half. The first half must be very fast and the other should be slow. Using default interpolator I am not getting the exact output what I want. If anyone has got the idea please help me. The code is

pushing_down_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <set android:ordering="sequentially" >
        <set>
            <translate
                android:duration="1000"
                android:fromYDelta="0"
                android:toYDelta="65%" />
        </set>
        <set>
            <translate
                android:duration="1500"
                android:fromYDelta="65%"
                android:toYDelta="100%p" />
        </set>
    </set>

</set>
```

pushing_down_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <set android:ordering="sequentially" >
        <set>
            <translate
                android:duration="500"
                android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
                android:toYDelta="-35%" />
        </set>
        <set>
            <translate
                android:duration="1000"
                android:fromYDelta="-65%p"
                android:toYDelta="0" />
        </set>
    </set>

</set>
```

in the main activity

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_out,R.anim.push_down_in);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Not working properly` can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: When the next activity opens, the current activity has to go out through bottom way and the other activity has to come from the top. I am opening the second activity, so the first activity has to go out in that 65% has to go faster after that the remaining should be slow. like in objectAnimator we have more that two animation put to gether.

Comment: only the last half animation is being displayed. But the first half is not shown at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think `android:ordering` will be ignored if you're using `ViewAnimations`.
Since you're only trying to make an animation which slows down over time you can use an `interpolator` as well. See the following code:

#### pushing_down_out.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

#### pushing_down_in.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

So I basically just merged your translate-animations into one and applied an interpolator. The interpolator takes care of "making" the animation fast at first and slowing it down gradually over time.

Following all available Interpolators:

```
@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator
@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator
@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator
@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator
@android:anim/bounce_interpolator
@android:anim/cycle_interpolator
@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator
@android:anim/linear_interpolator
@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator
```

You can read more about them in the [Docs (click)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween).

#### Edit - Customize Interpolator

It's also possible to customize the speed of the interpolator. Just create a new *.xml file in your `res/anim` folder and add the following lines:

```
<accelerateDecelerateInterpolator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:factor="2" />
```

The interesting line is the `android:factor`.
It's also possible to create your own Interpolator with your own formula. You can read more about it [here (click)](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1078).

Comment: It is ok. But i need to customize the interpolator itself.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use this in my case. for the first half duration is 500 and the next half duration is 1000. Thanks

Comment: Well if you're trying to stick exactly to this schedule you'll need to create an own interpolator and this is more of a mathematical question rather than a programming specific (the post I've linked in my post explains this pretty good). I'd recommend you to use the `accelerate_interpolator` - smooth acceleration over the whole course. ;)